# The JSON object sent from android application is null when i want to access him in java servlet

Tags: android, json, servlets

I am writing an application in android and i am sending a json object to a java servlet.

This is the android code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
JSONObject jsonObjectToPass  = returnJsonStringObject();
List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonGPSParameter",jsonObjectToPass.toString()));
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
entity.setContentType("application/json");   
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
post.setEntity(entity);
response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

This is the java servlet code

```
request.getParameter("jsonGPSParameter");
```

The problem is that the getParameter() method return null.
Im not be able to spot the problem.
If someoane can help me it would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: so you've checked `jsonObjectToPass.toString()`isn't null?

Comment: yes i have checked and is not null

Answer (score 1):

For the code to work proper i have to remove the next to lines from android code:

```
entity.setContentType("application/json");   
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```